# Show sum is holomorphic with Morera's Theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

Let $c_n$ be a bounded sequence of complex numbers. Show that $\sum_{r=1}^\infty c_n \frac{z^n}{1+z^n}$ is holomorphic at any complex z, $|z|<1$. I know this question has been asked and answered here before, but I want a very specific proof. I remember seeing a proof using Morera's Theorem, which states that given a continuous function such that for any closed path its integral is zero, then it is holomorphic. Can anyone help me with that? I don't remember how the theorem was applied.

Comment: To use Morera's theorem I suppose you'd first want to justify exchanging integration and summation, then argue why $\int_\gamma c_n \frac{z^n}{1 + z^n} \, d z = 0$ for $\gamma$ any closed (piecewise $C^1$/triangular, etc.) path in the open disk. Depending on the tools you have available, this isn't too bad (e.g., what are the poles?).

Comment: How do you show that $f$ above is continuous? You need some kind of uniform continuity for the series and that more or less proves holomorphicity (the fact that a series of holomorphic functions that converges uniformly on compacts has a holomorphic limit is precisely done using Morera and interchanging series and integrals)